# TIBCO Repository instance name is invalid. It must start with the characters

Tags: tibco, tibco-rv

I am new to Tibco. till now all my deployments went fine but suddenly while deploying on one of the machine it failed. I checked application management log which says

```
    TIBCO Repository instance name is invalid. It must start with the characters <domain_name>".
```

Domain name is the correct name I have no clue where else to check. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the instance name you want to deploy start with the domain name *followed by a dash*?

Hope that helps...

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/administrator/5.7.1-march-2012/doc/html/tib_TIBCOAdmin_server/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=tib_TIBCOAdmin_server&file=admin_server.3.118.htm (POF-12096)